# How to get a JSON file from another domain using cross domain - javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain-policy

this is the json file im trying to work with:
http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json
Im trying to retrieve the "data" array which is empty for most of the time.

Im having some issues with cross domain, i get an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin ' error message.

```
$.ajax({
  url : "http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json",
  type : 'GET',
  crossDomain: true,
  data : "json", 
  dataType : "json",
  success : function(res) {
    console.log('res',res);
  }
});
```

I also tried some jsonp ways to get the data but i had no success.
Can someone help me fix my code?

Comment: You're missing a `}` for the `success` function at the very least.

Comment: Also that site doesn't support JSONP which is the very least of what you need.

Comment: you are correct. I didnt copy the code properly. So how can i retrieve it with json?

Answer (score -1):

JSONP is really a simply trick to overcome `XMLHttpRequest` same domain policy.
So try to replace "json" by "jsonp" for the `dataType` attribut like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json",
    type : 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    data : "json", 
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(res) {
        console.log('res',res);
    }
});
```

EDIT :

A solution would be to server (php, java), which retrieves the json file and re-expose it. 
Then use the jquery script to retrieve the json from your server.

Example php code :

```
header("Content-Type:application/json");
echo file_get_contents("http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json");
```

Comment: This only works if the server supports JSONP which it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

This code overcomes the error that you are facing. dataType should be "jsonp" for Jquery to consider it as an Ajax request.  (Tested with latest version of Jquery 2.1.1)

```
 $.ajax({
         url : "http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json",
         type : 'GET',
         crossDomain: true,
         data : "json", 
         dataType : "jsonp",
         success : function(res) {
            console.log('res',res);
         }
      });
```

Comment: Ok, i used the newest version of jquery now and tested your code. Now i get an error :" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "  how do i overcome this?

Comment: This only works if the server supports JSONP which it doesn't.

Comment: @Vandervidi, I think that is an encoding problem. I don't have an answer for that problem, but probably setting the character encoding of the response to the right character encoding may solve the problem.

Comment: @Andy, I am not sure if the server supports JSONP or not, but the above code does fetch the data from that URL using JSONP. I can see the data, but the JSON parser is not able to parse it because of some character encoding issue.